# How do I get rid of that extra line at the end of my custom algorithmicx block?

Tags: algorithmicx

I'm using the `algorithmicx` package and have created a custom block called `\On`, but even with the `noend` option for `algpseudocode` I get an extra blank line at the end of the block.

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

% Defines custom \On ... \EndOn block
\algblockdefx[ON]{On}{EndOn}
  [2]{\textbf{on}~#1~\textbf{from}~#2~\textbf{do}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \On{$foo$}{$bar$}
        \State baz
      \EndOn
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: Custom ON-block in algorithmicx package]

As you can see, I get an extra blank line.  The predefined blocks like `\If` and `\For`, however, work as expected with the `noend` option.

I've read the documentation several times, but am still clueless in how I would fix this.

I'm using pdflatex from MacTeX (TeX Live) 2013.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem, but I came up with the following workaround after looking into the `algpseudocode` source code:

```
% Tell algorithmicx not to print an empty line if `noend' option is set 
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ALG@noend}{t}}%
  {\algtext*{EndOn}}
  {}%
\makeatother
```

[image]

The need for such a fix for each user-defined block can be considered a bug in `algpseudocode`, in my opinion. Perhaps you should drop the maintainer an email...

---

**Edit**: In case you decide not to use the `noend` option, the following definition for your "On" block probably makes more sense.

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicon{\textbf{on}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicfrom{\textbf{from}}
\algblockdefx[ON]{On}{EndOn}[2]
  {\algorithmicon\ #1\ \algorithmicfrom\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicon}
```

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

% Defines custom \On ... \EndOn block
\algnewcommand\algorithmicon{\textbf{on}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicfrom{\textbf{from}}
\algblockdefx[ON]{On}{EndOn}[2]
  {\algorithmicon\ #1\ \algorithmicfrom\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicon}

% Tells algorithmicx not to print an empty line if `noend' is set 
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ALG@noend}{t}}%
  {\algtext*{EndOn}}
  {}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \On{$foo$}{$bar$}
        \State baz
      \EndOn
    \end{algorithmic}
  \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I defer to your answer and have deleted my own.

Comment: Thank you so much! (and thanks for Steven as well) I believe this is the best we can do given the state of the package code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\algblockdefx[ON]{On}{EndOn}
[2]{\textbf{on}~#1~\textbf{from}~#2~\textbf{do}}
{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
```

Just strech the vertical space to 0

---

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
%case block 
\algblockdefx[caseBlock]{case}{endCase}
[1]{\textbf{case} #1 \textbf{of}}
{\textbf{end case}}
%
%caseToken block
\algblockdefx[caseTokenBlock]{caseToken}{endCaseToken}
[1]{\textbf{#1: }}
{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
%
%noEnd block
\algblockdefx[noEndBlock]{noEnd}{noEndEnd}
[1]{#1}
{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
%

\begin{algorithmic}[0]
  \Procedure{\textit{factor}}{}
  \noEnd{\textbf{Begin}}
  \case{token}
  \caseToken{(}
  \State match(\textbf{(})
  \State exp
  \State match(\textbf{)})
  \endCaseToken
  \caseToken{\textit{number}}
  \State match(\textit{\textbf{number}})
  \endCaseToken
  \noEnd{\textbf{else: } \textit{error}}
  \noEndEnd
  \endCase
  \noEndEnd
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image: no ending]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you put a complete example with a screenshot to see your solution? Thank you very much.