# algpseudocode: Is it possible to make the "noend" option work with custom blocks?

Tags: algorithmicx

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51295/algpseudocode-without-end-block-text) provides several good answers on creating custom `algpseudocode` blocks with no ending tag.

Based on that, I was wondering if such custom blocks can be redefined in order to detect the `noend` option, which for the standard blocks and loops makes their final indicator disappear.

Should it be done with a custom command tracking the existence of `noend`? Is there an internal flag inside `algorithmicx` that can be used?

I think it can have the following structure (not an actual solution, but a rough sketch):

```
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\ifthenelse{\undefined{\noEndDetector}}{ % A command "sensing" the *noend* option
    \algdef[SE]{...} % Definition considering ending keywords
}{
    \algdef[SxNE]{...} % Definition without ending keywords
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a bit of research it seems [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172054/how-do-i-get-rid-of-that-extra-line-at-the-end-of-my-custom-algorithmicx-block) effectively answers my query.

As it turns out, there is a flag `\ALG@noend` that can be checked in order to determine if the option `noend` has been passed to the package.

**Code snippet (taken from the question)**

```
% Defines custom \On ... \EndOn block
\algnewcommand\algorithmicon{\textbf{on}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicfrom{\textbf{from}}
\algblockdefx[ON]{On}{EndOn}[2]
  {\algorithmicon\ #1\ \algorithmicfrom\ #2\ \algorithmicdo}
  {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicon}

% Tells algorithmicx not to print an empty line if `noend' is set 
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ALG@noend}{t}}%
  {\algtext*{EndOn}}
  {}%
\makeatother
```